# More than one Foreign Key from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a problem with this MySQL Statment. So basicly i have a table called games and i want to 
display this table on my website. Table games has Foregin Keys like developer_id,
publisher_id, categorie_id, platform1_id, platform2_id, platform3_id, platform4_id, platform5_id.
I have 5 of platform because in Table platforms i have 5 records (PC, PS4, XB1, SWITCH, MOBILE). (If you guys know any better and easier solution to these platforms pls tell me.)
So now my output on my website works but for example instead of showing developer name it shows
it's ID. I know i have to INNER JOIN them and i probbably can INNER JOIN all foregin keys but the
platform one. Because i dont know how to INNER JOIN if you have more then one FK from one table.

If you need more info tell me. I will also include picture of my DB and my PHP code where i SELECT from table games.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['developer_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['publisher_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['categorie_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['platform1_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['platform2_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['platform3_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['platform4_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['platform5_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['game_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['relese_date'].'</td>';
    $intro = $row['introduction'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    echo '<td>'.$row['rating'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

[Picture of my DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmFgb.png)

Comment: You're getting the id for all the other fields too right, like categorie, platform, etc? Do you want all the values from those tables too?

Comment: yes i want the values from them too.

Comment: From that image, many of the relationships look like they're `many-to-many` (one game can have multiple platforms, one platform can have multiple games) ... so you're probably not going to want a `JOIN` in that case as that'll retrieve the same game data each time for each platform (unless you go down a really clunky `GROUP_CONCAT ... GROUP_BY` sort of route) - you might be better off fetching the platforms separately inside the loop, if you **really** need them at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT games.game_name, games.relese_date, games.introduction, games.rating, games.description, dev.name as developer, pub.name as publisher, (SELECT * FROM platforms WHERE platforms.id in (games.platform1_id,games.platform2_id,games.platform3_id,games.platform4_id,games.platform5_id)) as plats 
FROM games 
    INNER JOIN developers AS dev ON dev.id = games.developer_id 
    INNER JOIN publishers AS pub ON pub.id = games.publisher_id 
WHERE games.id = $id
```

Keep in mind that the platforms will be listed as a collection under the property plats, and each of those items will be an object of properties as.

E.X.

```
  return object=>
      developer_id
      publisher_id
      categorie_id
      plats => [
        platform1_id=>name, 
        platform2_id=>name, 
        platform3_id=>name, 
        platform4_id=>name, 
        platform5_id=>name
      ]
      game_name
      relese_date
      introduction
      description
      rating
```